# How can I pass by reference considering inheritance?

Tags: c++11, templates, inheritance

[Here's](https://godbolt.org/z/v8c9z45a6) my scenario (notice the code I can edit, the code I cannot):

```
#include <iostream>

// the follow is untouchable (from sdk)
struct Base { };

template <class TParamQuantity = Base>
TParamQuantity* configParam(int paramId) { return NULL; }

// the follow is my code (can edit as I want)
struct BaseParamScaler { };
struct LogParamScaler : BaseParamScaler { };

template <BaseParamScaler &T>
struct QRange : Base { };

LogParamScaler gLogParamScaler;

int main()
{
    configParam<QRange<gLogParamScaler>>(0);
}
```

What I'd like to know is being able to pass `BaseParamScaler` (and its childs) to `configParam` template method (which come from sdk).

Is there any way of doing this in `C++11`? Or how would you do this in some fancy way?

Note: if pass by point/value/whatever is permitted, I can do that way. But I believe stay with template is mandatory, having `configParam` working with them.

**EDIT**

A first approch that seems to work is adding the typename of the template itself, such as:

```
template <typename T, T &S>
struct QRange : Base { };
```

and than invoking as:

```
configParam<QRange<LogParamScaler, gLogParamScaler>>(0);
```

But I'm not sure how elegant is this solution.

Comment: As shown, you can pass any type to `configParam`, and it would nicely and reliably give you a null pointer of that type. It's unclear what the point of the exercise is - it looks like a very elaborate no-op. There must be more to this story that you neglected to mention. What is `configParam` supposed to do - surely not just return null?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik here's the configParam method https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/blob/f1576e2bb870da297789300117accb9d5fe44c5e/include/engine/Module.hpp#L125

Comment: I don't see why the code you've shown wouldn't work with that `configParam` implementation. Do you encounter some problem when you try that? What prompted you to ask?

Comment: Alternatively, you could make `QRange` a normal non-template class, and pass a scaler to it after `configParam` call. Something like `configParam<QRange>(...)->setScaler(gLogParamScaler);` . Note how `configParam<T>` creates a new `T` object (using its default constructor) and returns a pointer to it, so you can adjust it further.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you mean "my first approch" as my code? Yes it works, but its verbose (pass both the type and the reference, which must always be global and with static storage duration...). For example: pass only the reference would be better, if only I can do It with any child of BaseParamScaler...

Comment: In C++17 you can write `template <auto& Scaler> ...`. But in C++11 I don't think you can avoid explicitly spelling out the type. Or, like I said, you can make `QRange` a non-template and pass the scaler to it at run time. Then it wouldn't have to be a global variable.